# Convert htaccess sef rewrite to lighttpd

Tags: lighttpd

I read link: http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModRewrite

But I don't find how to sef_rewrite

htaccess
    RewriteRule . index.php?sef_rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

Could you help convert to lighttpd ?

Answer (score 0):

lighttpd not using sef_rewrite
Please using:

```
url.rewrite-once = (

  "^/(images|css|js|lib|payments|skins|var)/(.*$)" => "$0",
  "^/([^.*]+)$" => "/index.php/$1/",
)
```